# Cluster with Python and Dispy: cannot connect node

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, dispy

I'm trying to create a `raspberry-pi cluster` using [`dispy`](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/index.html) for a school project.

Just to try it, I'm using only one RPi as a `node` and my pc as `master` that request jobs.

Below the devices and their `ip`(s):

```
master (pc)  -->  192.168.1.106
node (rpi)   -->  192.168.1.105
```

**Node configuration**:

I execute `dispynode` in my node with:

```
sudo dispynode.py -i 192.168.1.105
```

Where:

- `sudo` to make sure there won't problem about permission
- `-i 192.168.1.105` to tell the node which address set up for communication ([documentation](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/dispynode.html))

The console output:

```
2015...12:21 - dispynode - dispynode version 4.5
2015...12:21 - dispynode - serving 1 cpus at 192.168.1.105:51348
```

I said: "Seems good!"

**Master configuration**:

I've written a small `python` script to test the cluster:

```
import dispy

cluster = dispy.JobCluster(
    "/bin/ls",
    nodes=["192.168.1.105"],
    ip_addr="192.168.1.106"
)

cluster.stats()
```

Where:

- `cluster` will be a new `JobCluster` that have the following specs
- `"/bin/ls"` is the path of an executable, the job for the node
- `nodes` contains the addresses of nodes that will receive the job (in this case just one, my rpi)
- `ip_addr` is the address used by master for communication
- `cluster.stats()` print out the stats about the cluster created

**I expect just one node connected**, but when I run this script I got this stats:

```
2015...12:22 - dispy - Storing fault recovery information in "_dispy_2015..."

Node |  CPUs |    Jobs |    Sec/Job | Node Time Sec
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Total job time: 0.000 sec
```

As you can see **there isn't rpi node connected to master**...

Also the `fault recovery file` created is empty.

**How can I connect node to master?**

**I'm using in the wrong way `dispynode` or master script?**

NOTES & USEFUL:

- Obiuvsly I've installed `dispy` in both devices.
- I can reach the node with `ping` from master and vice versa.
- [`ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) is disabled.
- Documentation [here](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try submitting a job? Dispy might only initiate a connection when there is an actual job.